Movie where a girl with bruises dies at the end on a beach
All I remember is that a trio of friends have some sexual encounters with one another, and the female lead in the movie is dying at the end of the film.  One of the male characters finds her on a beach, with bruising on her body (like from HIV) and he leaves her there to die at the end.
I'm convinced that this is The Informers. It was a Brett Easton Ellis movie that ended like that. But my friend, who I'm asking for, disagrees.  
Can there really be two films where a girl with AIDs dies on a beach at the end?

Do you know the approximate year or decade of release?

In the novel "Captains of the sand" a girl (Dora) dies after sleeping with her boyfriend at the beach. However, she dies of a fever, not AIDS.
There is a TV series from the late 80s and a movie from 2011.  Maybe your friend saw one of them?
